Why does statistical model over Cartesian product space yield likelihood for prediction of next element?
This is not a question about how to estimate likelihood, but rather about bridging the gap between intuition and theory.
Motivating setting
Let's say we observe a sample of 10 bits $\{1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1\}$, and based on this we estimate $\mathbf{p}(x=1) = 0.5$. So given the 11th bit $x_{11}$, we know the likelihood that it is one is $0.5$.
Now more formally, let there be a vector $\mathbf{x}$, taking value in the Cartesian product sample space $\Omega^n$, where each $\Omega = \{0,1\}$. Now suppose the distribution is in the exponential family with sufficient statistic $\mathbb{\phi}(x) = x$, mean $\mu = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{p}}[\mathbb{\phi}(x)] = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and distribution of form $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu) = exp( \mathbf{x}'\mu + A(\mu) )$, where $A$ is the log partition function. After observing many examples of $\mathbf{x} \in \Omega^n$, what have we estimated? And what is the likelihood that a single bit is $1$ having observed examples from $\Omega^n$?
question
This is the part there's some mismatch between intuition and what is written above. Because the samples from $\Omega^n$ are n bit strings, but the expectation of the sufficient statistics of the samples (read the mean) is the likelihood that a single bit is 1. And yet the probability function $ \mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu)$ is really the likelihood a single $n$ bit string in $\Omega^n$ takes on any value. So for example if the distribution is uniform, then:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x};\mu) = \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{equation}
for every n-bit string. There is no way we can get $1/2$ from that, unless we are asking for the set of $n$-bit strings where half of the bits are 1, and again assuming uniform distribution over all $n$-bit strings. And you certainly cannot write $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x}=1;\mu)$ based on that, because again the $\mathbf{p}$ here is measuring the sample space $\Omega^n$, not a single $\Omega$.
additional reading about exponential family and sample space constructions that motivated my confusion

Why do we need sigma-algebras to define probability spaces?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WvdpFqptZk

https://cba.mit.edu/events/03.11.ASE/docs/Wainwright.1.pdf



Because this post seems to conflate likelihoods, estimated likelihoods, and sufficient statistics, you might find it useful to review the definitions.

@whuber i thought in the exponential family the expectation of sufficient statistics in the first degree is the mean, and in the second order it's the variance etc. So for Bernoullii, the mean is just the average of the bits, which is the likelihood that the coin will and heads?

"Mean" has two natural senses here, as the expectation of the random variable used to model any bit and as the arithmetic mean of the bits.  You seem to confound the two in your statements.
